# Reaching Apollo client from dispatched redux actions for GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am trying to integrate the Apollo into my react-app.

I want to dispatch an action with a query argument and handle that query inside this action and pass the resolved promise as a payload to the respective reducer.

My approach is the following;

I have a `client.js` file

```
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({ uri: 'https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/cixos23120m0n0173veiiwrjr' }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

export default client
```

Then I have the following action to be dispatched from my component.

```
import client from '../graphclient'

export function gQLFetch(query) {

  const data = client.query({query: query})

  return {
    type: "gQL_FETCH",
    payload: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      data.then(response => resolve(response)).catch(error => reject(error))
    })
  }
}
```

Finally, my reducer handles the dispatched action and returns the state

```
const apiReducer = (state=[], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "gQL_FETCH_FULFILLED":
      state = action.payload.data.allMovies
      break;
  }
  return state;
}

export default apiReducer
```

That just works fine for me.

However, the documentation for Apollo suggests defining the `client` inside your index.js file and using `<ApolloProvider>` tag at the top of the component tree with `client` property to pass the client to the whole application like so;

```
ReactDOM.render(<ApolloProvider client={client}><Provider store={store}><App /></Provider></ApolloProvider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**My first question:** Is my approach a good practice? I feel like it is not, since `<ApolloProvider>` offers a way to serve the client to the whole application.

**Then my second question comes:** How can I reach client inside my redux action to pass the query parameter?

Answer (score 0):

`ApolloProvider` HoC for me makes sense if you want to populate/inject data directly into a component. If you want to have a different data management you'll probably create your own client requests and data fetching mechanisms.

The way of how you handle the asynchronous request is not correct tho. You should be using redux-thunk or redux-saga to manage such side effects. The reducer function should be synchronous and receive only the final fetched data. As I can see it in your example the reducer receives a promise which needs to be handled via `.then` method which is missing. Maybe you are using a middleware or something? I'll suggest to read more about redux-saga and dispatch three actions - `REQUEST`, `REQUEST_SUCCESSFUL` and `REQUEST_FAILURE`.

Comment: I'm using `redux-promise-middleware` to handle the promise, hence the type name of `gQL_FETCH_FULFILLED` in the switch of the reducer. Is that fine?